# Twisted IK handles. mesh is twisted. what am I doing wrong?

Tags: animation, rigging, inverse-kinematics

it is my first time really using blender to make a rigged 3D humanoid with IK handles. for some reason, my model is very twisted and contorted after applying automatic weights. and I've been unable to figure out what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it.

could someone who is experienced tell me what I might be doing wrong? or how to fix these issues?

Here is my blend file!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Instead of giving a *Copy Rotation* constraint to your feet, you could parent them to the *IK* controllers in *Edit* mode. But if you want to keep the *Copy Rotation* for some reason, choose the Z axis and *Space > Local Space/Local Space*.
- In *Edit* mode, bend the knees a bit forward so that Blender knows in what direction to bend them.
- In *Pose* mode, select the lower legs and in the *IK* constraint, change their *Angle* to 180°.
- I'm not sure about the spine orientation, it would probably be better if you switched the bones direction, they should point upwards.
- It's better to create a root bone, parent the first spine, the controller and the target bones to it.